# Azure Service bus topic: why messages seem to be eaten by receiver?

Tags: node.js, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a service bus topic that ingest telemetry messages outgoing from one of my servers ('telemetry-topic') at a rate of approximately 1 message every 10 seconds.
I have a web (site) front that subscribes to the 'telemetry-subscription' that consumes the 'telemetry-topic'.
What I witness is that the more front I run, the least message frequency it receives. I sounds like my topic acts as a queue…

What I should see is that any front -no matter the number of them— should sustain de approx 1 message very 10 seconds.

Note: My stack is node.

The receiver:

```
async function serviceBusTelemetrySubscribe(props) {
    const module = ' Service bus telemetry'
    const {enter, leave, log, warn, error} = SDK.logFunctions(module, {
        verboseLevel: 1,
        verboseEnterLeave: true,
    })

    try {
        enter()

        log('Subscribing with given processMessage', props.processMessage, 'processError', props.processError)

        const {processMessage, processError} = props

        // connection string to your Service Bus namespace
        const connectionString = 'XXXX'

        // == Topic & subscription names
        const topicName = 'telemetry-topic'
        const subscriptionName = 'telemetry'

        // == Create a Service Bus client using the connection string to the Service Bus namespace
        const sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString)
        log('Service bus client', sbClient)

        // == Create a receiver for "all telemetry" subscription.
        const receiver = sbClient.createReceiver(topicName, subscriptionName)
        log('Service bus receiver for subscription name "', subscriptionName, '" is:', sbClient)

        // == Function to handle messages, which provide a default one
        const myMessageHandler = processMessage || (async (messageReceived) => {
            log(`received message: ${messageReceived.body}`)
        })

        // == Function to handle any errors, which provide a default one
        const myErrorHandler = processError || (async (error) => {
            error(error)
        })

        log('Subscribing with actual processMessage', myMessageHandler, 'processError',myErrorHandler)

        // == Subscribe and specify the message and error handlers
        const sbSubscription = receiver.subscribe({
            processMessage: myMessageHandler,
            processError: myErrorHandler
        })
        log('Service bus subscription', sbSubscription)

        // == Return cleanup method
        return async () => {
            log('Closing Service bus…')
            // Waiting long enough before closing the sender to send messages
            await delay(5000)
            log('Closing Service bus subscription…')
            await sbSubscription.close()
            log('Closing Service bus receiver…')
            await receiver.close()
            log('Closing Service bus client…')
            await sbClient.close()
        }
    }
    catch(err) {
        error(err)
    }
    finally {
        leave()
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that the point of subscriptionName - to separate different consumers, each of which should get their own copy of incoming messages? I don't have experience with Azure topics, but it usually works this way in other brokers - like a shared subscription in Apache Pulsar, or consumer groups in Kafka.

Comment: Do you mean I should assign a unique subs name to each front?

Comment: I think so, yes. It's my interpretation of this paragraph from the docs: "Each published message is made available to each subscription registered with the topic."